# GWT-SyncProxy for android : No remoteService in the classpath

Tags: java, android, gwt, classpath, gwt-syncproxy

In android client consuming my LoginService remote service, in order to connect user to the application.

I use gwt-syncproxy librairie to acces to my remote interface.   And the following warning occured:

```
RpcPolicyFinder:No RemoteService in the classpath
```

followed by :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 

http:// localhost: . . . /. . ./application/application.nocache.js
```

Is there someone who had experienced this type of  trouble ?

Comment: You might be better off posting this as an issue on the google code page of [gwt-syncproxy](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [Android](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/wiki/Android) and [CommonIssues](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/wiki/CommonIssues) wiki pages for the project as these clarify some common issues with the library.

In the meantime, more specifically, I often see this type of issue (though not this exactly) when the library has not been GWT-compiled or if the local server is not running where the Android app is expecting to find it. If you're not using App-Engine and are testing locally, make sure you are using Android's host Loopback interface with the `#setLoginUrl` method ([GAELogin](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/wiki/Android#Google_App_Engine_Login), [Android Emulator networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)).

Try posting the full error with details so we can see where it might be pointing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by a few reason:
1. You site is required login. And I checked the code of SyncProxy(0.5), it doesn't support if a site is secure.
2. SyncProxy will download some files from server side, for example:

```
compilation-mappings.txt
*.nocache.js
*.cache.html
*.gwt.rpc
```

3. If SyncProxy cannot download them, this error may occur, please check it these files can be download and the uri and name format of them is as default.
4. I was contacting with the owner of SyncProxy to improve this feature to support basic cookie/sessionid checking of auth.
   https://github.com/jcricket/gwt-syncproxy/issues/46#issuecomment-89271311